# Joining traces in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to make a shape conformed by a few traces, many of which are not continuous. By the moment, I've managed to create this shape with different traces.

I've tried calling them the same name, but this didn't work. For instance:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,0], y=[3,1,1],name="Name"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,1,2], y=[0,2,0],name="Name"))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Is it possible to plot this shape into an unique trace?

Comment: What would you like to achieve if you were to.`xx = [1,2,0]+[0,1,2];yy = [3,1,1]+[0,2,0];
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=xx, y=yy,name="Name"));fig.show()`

Comment: The problem by running this is that both shapes are joined with an additional trace. I'd like to create an unique shape with non continious traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Plotly, if you have two independent segments belong to the same shape, and you want to plot each one without any connection, you must do that with 2 traces but you can color the segments of the same shape with the same color and use `legendgroup` to control all segment under the same shape:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(x=[1,2,0], y=[3,1,1],
                marker_color="blue", legendgroup="1", name="Shape1"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,1,2], y=[0,2,0],
                marker_color="blue", legendgroup="1", showlegend=False))
fig.show()
```

[image]